# How to sync data across all iDevices

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud

I currently have an application that works on my iPad,So when i save a particular project then  it has to save and sync across all my iDevices,how do i acheive that? what api's are available?

Thanks

Comment: What options has your research found?

Comment: @Wain i know that i can store data on iCloud using 3 different ways
1)Key value store (small amounts of data)
2)Core data (Large amounts of data)
3)Subclassing UIDocument (Can be stored as individual files that can read/write/update/delete)
what is the ideal way to store my projects on iCloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on your requirement.

you can use iCloud for syncing the data/files all the iOS devices user has authenticated with the same account.

but if you want to sync within the app data according the user profile, like user has two devices and login with two different accounts then in that case you can use your own server to sync data manually by your APIs.